# xcb_shm_get_image equivalent in Xlib

Tags: c, linux, xlib, xorg, xcb

I am currently porting a program from XCB to XLib*. Now I have a point where the image of the XServer gets grabbed via `xcb_shm_get_image`. `xcb_shm_get_image` has the option in defining what portions of the image you want to grab, given `x` and `y`, `width` and `height` parameters. Is there a way to achieve the same with `XShmGetImage`?

*XCB has a Bug in the current debian stable rendering it useless for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bool XShmGetImage(
    register Display *dpy,
    Drawable d,
    XImage *image,
    int x, int y,
    unsigned long plane_mask);
```

With [XShmGetImage()](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xextproto/shm.html#XShmGetImage) you specify *x* & *y* as arguments to the function, and the *height* and *width* are taken from the *image* you pass as the destination to copy the pixels into.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly the information I was looking for. Did I overread it in the docs?

Comment: @Nidhoegger - the x & y parameters are covered in the docs, but I had to look at the source to see where the height & width come from.